# How to convert oddly formatted txt file to a xslx file?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, export-to-excel, txt

I have an oddly formatted xslx file that looks like this:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VLa9.png)

Here is the data link: https://pastebin.com/jTQnS0Jk

The variables correspond to the values under it. I.E Beta = 0.0 L/D = 14.68 and Fopt = 0.0. Then repeats the pattern.

I tried a multitude of txt to excel threads here and none really get the formatting correctly. Ideally, I would one variable in each column.

```
excel = "InitialModelGeneration_DegenGeom.polar" # Even though it is '.polar' it is read as a .txt file
mydata = pd.read_csv(excel, skiprows=6, delim_whitespace=True, header=None,
                     names=range(27))  # makes the excel sheet organized
mydata.to_excel("InitialModelGenerationVLMResults.xlsx", index=True)  # creates the excel file here
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("InitialModelGenerationVLMResults.xlsx",
                                  data_only=True)  # reads the excel
```

I was fully expecting the code to work, however, it seemed to have cutoff a large portion of my code.
[Results from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6uSE.png)

Comment: Can you share a few lines (*1 to 10*) as raw text of your `.polar` file ? Make sure to include at least two blocks.

Comment: sorry about that! Added it to the patebin link!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Data in images cannot be copied and pasted to be used for testing solutions to the problem. Links to off-site data are also not useful.

Answer (score 0):

[*Polar files*](https://www.seapilot.com/features/polars/) seems to be some fixed-format `.txt` files and [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) seems to do the job :

```
df = pd.read_fwf("InitialModelGeneration_DegenGeom.polar")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

    Beta  Mach             AoA             Re/1e6    CL  ...   CMl   CMm  CMn  FOpt
0   0.00  0.19  -15.000000000000   4.466239198109 -1.43  ... -0.00  5.54 0.00  0.00
1   0.00  0.19  -13.125000000000   4.466239198109 -1.23  ... -0.00  4.86 0.00  0.00
2   0.00  0.19  -11.250000000000   4.466239198109 -1.04  ... -0.00  4.18 0.00  0.00
..   ...   ...                                ...   ...  ...   ...   ...  ...   ...
14  0.00  0.19   11.250000000000   4.466239198109  1.33  ... -0.00 -3.81 0.00  0.00
15  0.00  0.19   13.125000000000   4.466239198109  1.53  ... -0.00 -4.53 0.00  0.00
16  0.00  0.19   15.000000000000   4.466239198109  1.74  ... -0.00 -5.25 0.00  0.00

[17 rows x 20 columns]
```